# Get data output from Sagemaker training step before pipeline executes

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

I'm saving output data as a part of my training step in my sagemaker pipeline. Some of this data is later used in another step for evaluation, not the model. Is there any way I can get the path before the execution? A pipeline variable is good enough. Just anything that lets me point to the s3 data path for later use as a ProcessingInput.
Example:

```
estimator = HuggingFace(
    py_version="py310",
    entry_point="entrypoint.py",
    source_dir=os.path.join("code", "nlp", "train"),
    transformers_version="4.28.1",
    pytorch_version="2.0.0",
    sagemaker_session=session,
    role=role,
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type="ml.p3.2xlarge",
)


step_train = TrainingStep(
    name="TrainHuggingFaceModel",
    estimator=estimator,
    inputs={
        "data": TrainingInput(s3_data="PathToData"),
    },
    cache_config=CACHE_CONFIG,
)
```

From the training step, I would like to get the training output. If this does not work, any other suggestions? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to step output for example :

`step_process.properties.ProcessingOutputConfig.Outputs["train_data"].S3Output.S3Uri`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/build-and-manage-steps.html#build-and-manage-data-dependency

Comment: That is for a processing step and not for a training step? I've been going through the properties of the training step and while it contains a Outputdataconfig, it only links to the bucket.

Comment: Can you not then use a Pipeline parameter: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/build-and-manage-parameters.html ?

Comment: The idea is to pipe the output s3 URI to the next step in the pipeline. A pipeline parameter is fine, but the s3 uri in the output is stored in modified every time the pipeline executes.